# eclipse java multithread program debugging

Tags: scjp

while debugging the java Multithreading  program i put breakpoints. after start method is invoking the control is not going to run menthod can you please let me know the debug procedure.

sample code

```
class Test extends Thread { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        try { 
            Thread t = new Thread(new Test());
            t.start(); 
            t.start(); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
             System.out.print("e "); 
        } 
    } 

    public void run() { 
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
            System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " "); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more explicit or provide some code.

Answer (score 8):

Debugger starts with main thread, since your breakpoint is in main thread.
`t.start()` spawns a new thread.
But the debugger will continue with the main thread itself.

If you want to debug the newly created thread, then you have to set a breakpoint in `run()` method also.Then the debugger control goes to the newly created thread, but it is invisible to the user.

If you want to see the control in `run()` method of newly created thread, then you have to follow the below steps -

1. Put a breakpoint in `run()` method along with the `main()` method.
2. Start debugging the program till you hit the statement `t.start()`.
3. After completing `t.start()`, go to "Debug" view. There you will find 2 threads running.(You can find the "Debug" view in eclipse by going to "**Window -> Show View -> Debug**").

   - First one is main thread
   - Second one is newly created thread (e.g. [Thread-1] )
4. Click on the second thread to see the control in run method.
5. After completion of your thread execution, go to the "**Debug**" view again and click on the main thread to continue with the main thread debugging.

**Note:** If you continue with the main thread after 3rd step towards the end of the thread, then you will not be able to debug your new thread.